# Difference between different forms of past tense

Tags: difference, word-difference

What is the difference between these sentences?

> 1. I shopped.
> 2. I was shopping.
> 3. I did some shopping.

When do we use them?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. StackExchange values questions where the questioner can show some initial research effort, so that we can better ascertain your level of expertise. What grammars or other references have you consulted? There are many other past forms as well, e.g. *I did shop*, *I have shopped*, *I had shopped*, *I had been shopping*. Moreover, in your third example, *shopping* is a gerund, and not the main verb, which changes how it can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are all in the **past tense**, "shopped" and "shopping" were used as a **verb** in 1 and 2, but "shopping" was used as a **noun** in 3. Here are some examples:

**1.** "I shopped." is simple past tense, and shopped is a **verb**.

> I shopped at the grocery store.
>
> I shopped until I dropped*

*This is an idiom that means you shopped until you were very tired

Usage: making a statement that you shopped, easy to add detail about where you shopped at the end.

**2.** "I was shopping." is past continuous tense, and shopping is a **verb**.

> I was shopping with my friend until he had to leave.
>
> I was shopping for vegetables then found chocolate and was distracted.

Usage: for describing something that happened while shopping.

**3.** "I did some shopping." is simple past tense, and shopping is a **noun**.

> I did some shopping then I went home.
>
> I did some shopping for my mother.

Usage: similar to "I shopped", notice you can replace "I did some shopping." with "I shopped."

Comment: I appreciate your research on this; and also for the examples. +1